# Retrieve Kubernetes' Secret from Google Composer (Airflow)

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have an Apache Airflow working on Kubernetes (via Google Composer). I want to retrieve one variable store in Secret:

[image]

I need to consume the variables stored in this Secret from a DAG in Airflow.(python).

Comment: And what did you do to achieve your goal? What is your _specific_ problem?

Comment: the last sentence in the question: _I need to consume the variables stored in this Secret from a DAG in Airflow.(python)._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are stored as "Environment Vars", so in Python is quite easy:

```
import os
os.environ['DB_USER'])
```